# FontForge - glyph appears to be correct, but fills are wrong

Tags: font-forge

I used an Illustrator extension called FontSelf Maker to convert a series of designs to font glyphs, and I'm using FontForge to edit each individual font as necessary.

I cannot figure out what's going on with this specific glyph - the paths all seem right, but there are too many fills. I've tried a bunch of different options with intersecting paths and selecting different paths and nodes to no avail.

It looks like this:
[image: FontForge rendering]

It should look like this:
[image: Illustrator rendering]

What am I missing here?

Comment: I *think* your path *directions* could be wrong.

Comment: I'm not a very good font maker (this is for a project and only for specific extended Unicode glyphs, including private set ones) - how do I do that? I'm familiar with creating and working with vectors, if it helps.

Comment: Uh ... can't remember. I don't have FontForge installed right now. Check out [the manual](http://designwithfontforge.com/en-US/Using_the_Fontforge_Drawing_Tools.html). There's a chapter called "Cutting a shape within another" that talks about using *Element > Correct Direction*.

Comment: Used Element > Correct Direction on a single point and that fixed everything. Thanks!!

Comment: No problem. You should answer your own question then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by selecting a single node in the upper left circle segment that needed to be removed. and used Element > Correct Direction. Everything's groovy now.